# Common model in ExtJs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

​I have few grids which have lot of similar fields. I want to create a common model and extend from it as below :

```
Ext.define('my.model.MyModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ {
        name : 'fieldA'
    }, {
        name : 'fieldB'
    }
    ]
});


Ext.define('my.model.MyModelA', {
    extend : 'my.model.MyModel',
    fields : [ { // How do I add the extra columns in the subclass? 
            }
]
});
```

And same for grids.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the extra fields. The model will figure it out during definition time.

```
Ext.define('A', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name']
});

Ext.define('B', {
    extend: 'A',
    fields: ['age']
});

console.log(B.getFields());
```

Comment: ​How will it know not to overwrite the original fields?